# Integrate Angular2 into existing Grails3 app

Tags: angular, grails-3.0

I'm using grails 3.0.9 for existing application with web-app profile.

Recently I decided to integrate Angular2 into the app, but I'm not sure how to do it properly. I'm aware of the angular2 profile in Grails 3.2.1+ versions and I don't mind to update Grails. As I understand in this case multi-project build will be created with a separate project for the client and server applications. And I how several questions:

1) Why do we need to run both applications in parallel? What's the purpose to run client app concurrently? Why do we need client app at all? Is this profile for specific project architecture, where we have some client app talking to rest api service? In my case, I need just simple web-app with grails back-end + angular2 on the front-end. Do I understand it right that I shouldn't use angular2 profile for my app?

2) If the answer on previous question is NO. What's the proper way to integrate angular2 into grails3 web app, because of typescript the integration should be a bit different, as we need to compile typescript to javascript. + it would be nice to have source code auto-reloading for the angular part of app.